# How to output png in pycairo without compression

Tags: python, image, png, cairo, pycairo

I am trying to batch process a set of `png` files and output them as new `png`s which I then want to include in an MS Word document. I have written a script to do that for me which does what I want, however, I notice that the `png` being generated by pycairo seems to have been compressed. If I undertake the same steps manually in Inkscape and then ask it to save it as a "Cairo PNG" this is not the case. Similarly if I open the `test.svg` file generated by my pycairo script in Inkscape and then save it as a "Cairo PNG" in Inkscape I also get a better resolution. Is there an option for me to set the compression level in pycairo? Here is a trimmed-down MWE:

```
import cairo

pt_per_mm = 2.83465
width = int(200 * pt_per_mm)
height = int(250 * pt_per_mm)
img_width = int(100 * pt_per_mm)
img_height = int(50 * pt_per_mm)

surface = cairo.SVGSurface('test.svg',width,height)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)

image_surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png('reac_ranked_no_1.png')
real_img_height = image_surface.get_height()
real_img_width = image_surface.get_width()
width_ratio = float(img_width) / float(real_img_width)
height_ratio = float(img_height) / float(real_img_height)
ctx.save()
ctx.scale(width_ratio,height_ratio)
ctx.set_source_surface(image_surface)
ctx.paint()
ctx.restore()

surface.write_to_png('test.png')
surface.finish()
```

Comment: You can set a [fallback resolution](https://www.cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/surfaces.html#cairo.Surface.set_fallback_resolution). As per docs:"For backends that are natively vector-oriented, this function can be used to set the resolution used for these image fallbacks, (larger values will result in more detailed images, but also larger file sizes). Some examples of natively vector-oriented backends are the ps, pdf, and svg backends."

Comment: PNGs are *always* compressed; it's part of their specifications. (Assuming you don't mean "compression method: store" – this, technically, is still a form of 'zlib compatible compression', not "uncompressed".) I assume you mean something like "downsampling"?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps that was imprecise wording. My knowledge in this field is not the best but from what I can tell different levels of compression are possible (at least that's how I would assume Inkscape gets a better resolution). Similarly if I convert an eps into a png in IrfanView it gives me the option to set a compression level (ranging from "0" for "none" to "9" for "best"). Can I somehow control this "compression level" within pycairo? (You may be right that downsampling is the controlling factor here, I don't know how the conversion is implemented so am happy with whatever works.)